# how to input elements instead of another array, into end of array?

Tags: php

Due to bad DB design, there may be several values in a column @ each row in a table. So I had to take in every string, check if commas exist (multiple values) & place each element into the end of an array.

Did try out functions like strpos, explode, array_push etc. With the folllowing code, how do i input ONLY the multiple elements into the end of an array, without creating another & placing that into an existing array?

```
$test = array();
$test = array ("testing");
$str = 'a,b,c,d';
$parts = explode(',', $str);

array_push ($test, $parts);    //another array inserted into $test, which is not what I want
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_merge.

```
$test = array_merge($test, $parts);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/r7vaB